# When the animation has run once I can still see the text in a very light opacity, could someone please help remove this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When the animation has run once I can still see the text in a very light opacity, could someone please help remove this?

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/797BR/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.btn').click(function () {
     $('.tooltip').animate({
         opacity: 0,
     }, 0);
     $('.tooltip').animate({
         bottom: '40px',
         width: '163px',
         opacity: 1
     }, 400);
     $('.tooltip').css({
         'display': 'block',
     }).delay(1400);
     $('.tooltip').animate({
         opacity: 0,
         bottom: '30px'
     }, 200);
 });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's an optical illusion and it's just your eyes retaining the image for a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did observe your problem, I have to agree with Billy Moat in that it's an optical illusion. However there is a way that you can improve upon your tooltip. Currently after the first time it will actually stay visible just transparent. This allows you use to select the text (notice the mouse cursor change when hovering).

You can fix this by with using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to hide it after the animation is completed.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/nrtWK/)

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn').click(function () {
         $('.tooltip')
             .addClass('show')
             .animate({
                 opacity: 0,
             }, 0)
             .animate({
                 bottom: '40px',
                 width: '163px',
                 opacity: 1
             }, 400)
             .delay(1400);
         $('.tooltip')
             .animate({
                 opacity: 0,
                 bottom: '30px'
             }, 200);
         setTimeout(function () {
             $('.tooltip').removeClass('show');
         }, 2000);
     });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    visibility:hidden;
    width: 164px;
    left: 6px;
    display: block;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rusterholz.dk/btn.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
}
.tooltip.show {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me find a quick solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "complete"-callback of animate

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn').click(function () {
            $( '.tooltip' ).css( 'opacity', 0 )
            .animate( {
                bottom: '40px',
                width: '163px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 400, function() {

                $( '.tooltip' ).css( 'display', 'block' )
                .delay( 1400 )
                .animate( {
                    opacity: 0,
                    bottom: '30px'
                }, 200 );
            } );
        } );
    } );
```

I didn't test this

The problem may be that the 'animate'-functions will run at the same time which makes no sense, JavaScript works asynchronously with callbacks